# Render GSP view as compact html file

Tags: html, grails, web, render, gsp

I have gsp view files wherein tags are formatted for readability with whitespaces. I am expected to remove those so that the rendered html file is compact. So, is there a way in grails using plugin or any other means that I can tell grails to remove the whitespaces/newlines between tags and generate a compact view? I dont want to remove them from gsp file itself but only from the html file rendered by grails.

Comment: Do you use <!DOCTYPE html> at the top of your layout file, if you call one or at the top of your gsp file?

Comment: yeah... but how can it compact the rendered html.. isnt it a directive to browser... by render I am the tomcat/grails api building html from gsp..i want the html to not have any whitespace

Comment: This is a JSP thing, but I'd try it anyway. Put this at the top of your GSP: <%@ page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" %>

Comment: @Gregg - does not appear to be implemented yet: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-7623 (still marked as open)

Comment: i'm not sure about is functional to your problem, do you know Jtidy?http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/index.html

Comment: Hello, Trying to clean up unanswered. Did you solve this? Maybe you can answer your own question.

Comment: @Sumit Though you have a widely accepted question, May you please add some gsp samples and screenshots etc to give an example of what you want. It will give me more hints around solving this problem.

Comment: You can use HtmlCompressor. Here is the answer:
[Here is the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488592/is-there-such-thing-as-a-jsp-minifier-or-open-source-html-minifier)

Comment: So you have to catch the HTML content (that is generated) before it goes to the browser. Then trim all white-spaces and new lines!

Answer (score 4):

If the goal is to go easy on network transfer, enable the Spring Boot compression (gzip) in application.yml

```
server:    
    compression:
        enabled: true
        mime-types: application/json,application/xml,text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,application/javascript
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Gregg suggested,`<%@ page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" %>` should help.

Also you can use decorators:

https://github.com/grails/grails-core/pull/546

Comment: Nope not in gsp view pages

Answer (score -2):

How about using one of the yui-minify-resources or ui-performance plugins?

Here are the links:
http://grails.org/plugin/yui-minify-resources
http://grails.org/plugin/ui-performance

Comment: Thanks. But, it seems that they are no more maintained by their developers. Also, They only work on css and js files. Any idea about html?