# Output buffer to get current page code like ob_get_contents() of PHP in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, buffer, output, translate

I need get the entire HTML source code of page after process in JSP.

in PHP:

```
<?php
ob_start();
?>

{home}
{car}
{light}

<?php
$page = ob_get_contents(); // <<< I need that in JSP

ob_clean();

$page = str_replace("{home}", "Home", $page);
$page = str_replace("{car}", "Car", $page);
$page = str_replace("{light}", "Light", $page);

echo($page);
?>
```

How i can get the output buffer in JSP?

I try:

```
String ob = pageContext.pushBody().getString();
```

But not work.

It's possible make that using Java inside JSP page?

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to write something directly on the output buffer in scriptlet, you just use `out.println("whatever");`. But I don't recommend using scriptlets at all. Please provide more info about your exact specific problem.

Comment: No no no buddy. I need get the FINAL output buffer of page to make translation and minify the page. See example in PHP code.

Comment: Ok, got it. Note that it would be better doing this in a filter rather than in every page. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5488592/1065197